# Change datatype from char to int in VBSCRIPT

Tags: vbscript, crystal-reports

Hi I need your help guys!

I am new to the system I am using and I am working on customizing a report that uses crystal report, 
I need to get the value of the last page and compare this to the current page
(CurrentPage <> LastPage) , yet the data type of the Last Page is set to string/char..
I guess this is the reason why I can't get the result on the condition above. is there any way to change
its data type to Integer? or is there other way to get the LastPage integer value from a crystal reports without using the set variables for last page?

Thank You.

Comment: If you´d post what you have, we could help much more efficiently...

Answer (score 0):

Remember that ALL textbox values is always a string value no matter of the content.

```
'Private Sub TextBox1_Change()
    Dim IntValue As Integer

    If TextBox1.TextLength > 0 Then
        IntValue = TextBox1 * 1     ' method 1
        'IntValue = TextBox1 + 1 - 1 ' method 2
        'IntValue = TextBox1 + 0     ' method 3
        MsgBox "IntValue = " & IntValue
    End If

End Sub'
```

Comment: it's still not working. Thank you, but I guess this method did not change the data type of the string, this method only results concatenation of (String + 1 = "String1") and provides an error for (String * 1)

Answer (score 0):

CInt specifies the integer datatype. VBScript normally autoconverts.

Comment: The CInt function converts any number to the variant of subtype Integer. it is said here that this function is used for integers [CInt(AnyInteger)], Is this function also enables string? i.e.[CInt(STRING)]

Answer (score 0):

I have a different user id so ihave to reply here. This is a variant,

```
struct tagVARIANT {
VARTYPE vt;
WORD wReserved1;
WORD wReserved2;
WORD wReserved3;
union {
//  C++ Type      Union Name   Type Tag                Basic Type
//  --------      ----------   --------                ----------
    long          lVal;        // VT_I4                ByVal Long
    unsigned char bVal;        // VT_UI1               ByVal Byte
    short         iVal;        // VT_I2                ByVal Integer
    float         fltVal;      // VT_R4                ByVal Single
    double        dblVal;      // VT_R8                ByVal Double
    VARIANT_BOOL  boolVal;     // VT_BOOL              ByVal Boolean
    SCODE         scode;       // VT_ERROR
    CY            cyVal;       // VT_CY                ByVal Currency 
    DATE          date;        // VT_DATE              ByVal Date
    BSTR          bstrVal;     // VT_BSTR              ByVal String
    IUnknown      *punkVal;    // VT_UNKNOWN 
    IDispatch     *pdispVal;   // VT_DISPATCH          ByVal Object
    SAFEARRAY     *parray;     // VT_ARRAY|*           ByVal array
    // A bunch of other types that don't matter here...
    VARIANT       *pvarVal;    // VT_BYREF|VT_VARIANT  ByRef Variant
    void          * byref;     // Generic ByRef        
    };
 };
```

Variants normally autoconvert, need a string it changes to a string.

This is one OLE function (and probably what VB uses)

```
HRESULT VariantChangeType(VARIANT * pvDst, VARIANT * pvSrc, WORD wFlags, VARTYPE vt);
```

This function changes the type of a VARIANT without changing its value (if possible). To change a variable in place, make the destination the same as the source.

CInt forces it to be an integer, even if vbscript think it should be something else.

So a string containing 52 will be an integer if you try and add another number to it.

Also in basic a int is 16 bit and a long is 32 bit for compatability with 16 bit VB.

Comment: + sign adds numbers and concatinates strings. `A="5"
B=5
msgbox A + B
msgbox cint(A) + B
msgbox clng(A) + B
` all print 10